# How to use Formik ErrorMessage properly with formik using render props and design library for inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I want to trigger formik errors and touched whenever the input is clicked and the value is not correct .
I pass formik props to the input component like this :

```
const initialValues = {
    title: ''
};

const validationSchema = yup.object({
    title: yup.string().max(50, 'less than 50 words !!').required('required !!')
});

function Add() {
        <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema}>
            {(props) => {
                return (
                    <Form>
                                    <AddTitle props={props} />
                    </Form>
                );
            }}
        </Formik>
    );
}
```

Here I'm trying to display error message whenever the input is touched and there is an error with it like this :

```
import { Input } from 'antd';

function AddTitle(props) {
    console.log(props.props);
    return (
            <Field name="title">
                {() => {
                    return (
                        <Input
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                props.props.setFieldValue('title', e.target.value)
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                }}
            </Field>
            <ErrorMessage name="title" />
            <P>
                {props.props.touched.title && props.props.errors.title && props.props.errors.title}
            </P>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

But ErrorMessage and the paragraph below it doesn't work when the input is touched and empty .

In console log it shows that input doesn't handle formik touched method and it only triggers the error for it :

```
touched:
__proto__: Object
errors:
title: "less than 50 words !"
__proto__: Object
```

How can I use ErrorMessage properly while passing in formik props to a component and using a third library for inputs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding the onBlur to the input and ErrorMessage is working fine :

```
<Field name="title">
                {() => {
                    return (
                        <Input
                            onBlur={() => props.props.setFieldTouched('title')}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                props.props.setFieldValue('title', e.target.value);
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                }}
            </Field>
            <P class="mt-2 text-danger">
                <ErrorMessage name="title" />
            </P>
```